# werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a variable link, which sends a form but when the post happens I want the link to continue with the variable, this is my simplified code:

```
@app.route('/copass/<string:cod_ver>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def copass(cod_ver):
    rut_gen="/copass/{}".format(cod_ver)
         if request.method == 'POST':
             """Here is more code but it is not relevant, it is just compilation of the same form."""
             return render_template('user/cam_pass.html',rut_gen=rut_gen)
         else:
             return render_template('user/cam_pass.html',rut_gen=rut_gen)
```

this is my form in html cam_pass:

```
<form action="{{ url_for(rut_gen) }}" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cod_fpass" value="{{cod_fpass}}"/>
   <!--here are some input for the post -->
</form>
```

I have been looking at various comments about this error but it still isn't clear to me how to fix it, I have tried several but they haven't worked.

I hope that the variable link remains when I post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was very easy, have solved, don't have to use the function url_for(), only you have to send the run_gen to form
this is coding in python:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, session,get_flashed_messages
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/copass/<string:cod_ver>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def copass(cod_ver):
    print("entro copass")
    #print(url_for('/copass/{}'.format(cod_ver)))
    url='/copass/{}'.format(cod_ver)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        return  render_template('test.html',cod_fpass=cod_ver,url=url)
    else: 
        return  render_template('test.html',cod_fpass=cod_ver,url=url)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run()
```

this is coding html:

```
 <form action="{{url}}" method="post">
   
    <input  name="cod_fpass" value="{{cod_fpass}}"/>
    <input class="button-r" type="submit" value="REGISTER" />
  </form>
```